# Login to Instagram by flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, instagram

I'm building an app which is related to Instagram so I want user of my app first time login to their professional Instagram account and show something simple about their accounts. But I have a problem, I couldn't find any source or guidance for how to use Instagram login in my app. Is there any API to use that in flutter or not or any way?

Answer (score 0):

1. basically you can use Instagram API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/

All you need is just to use any flutter HTTP client and communicate with API.

2. Or you can try to use some flutter plugin like that: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_insta

Comment: sorry but it's not what i exactly want. if i use Instagram graph API, first time user should login to their Facebook account but i don't want that, i want first time login to Instagram account.

Comment: Have you tried to check other links in facebook docs? for example: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api